# How to monitor a network program in the linux ? What aspects need to consider and monitor?

Tags: networking

I develop a network program that is used to transfer files , it works . But I just know it can works , and I don't know how to monitor and evaluate it . So I want to know what aspects a network program usually need to consider and monitor and how to monitor .

Answer (score 0):

First make sure which protocol you have been used to send files (either TCP or UDP).

1.If you are using TCP at transport layer ,at the receiving end you can use **TCPDUMP**
packet analyzer to analyze all packets receiving on TCP port and its content.

2.If you want to analyze packets irrespective of protocols used at different layers, you can use **wireshark** packet analyzer to analyze all packets received on different networks like ethernet,PPP, loop back ,frame relay. you can use IP address of sender host as a reference to extract packets ( you need some reference to extract packets because wire shark will return all the packets received on the NIC interface). Once you extract the packets received from your sender host, you can analyze the packet payload to check whether files content has been received properly or not.

3.you can redirect data ( payload) of all received packets into some file. Once your program is done with receiving packets, you can check with that file to check data has been properly received or not. ( you can use this method only to test your client/server programs within a system)